# MySQL joins on two table with the same value

Tags: mysql, database

http://imgur.com/a/7kmGL

So I need to figure out how to join those two tables based on if the columns in both are 1, to ultimately get the HOUSEID key out. So essentially if one table has (1,0,0,0) it will give me all the HOUSEID's that have a (1) in the first column. I think it's an inner join but Im having trouble only selecting and matching columns with ones.

Comment: Post your code as text not images. Better if you set up a sql fiddle and you show us what you have done so far

Comment: A simple join should do it. Show us what query you have tried and why it is not working? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ClientID, HouseID
FROM Preferences  p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Amenities  a
ON p.Pool <= a.Pool AND  p.Jacuzzi <= a.Jacuzzi AND
   p.Backyard <= a.Backyard AND p.Smart <= a.Smart
```

I you are looking for a specific client, add

```
WHERE ClientID = 13
```